# Как вставить в документ написанный в HTML 5 код в PHP

Tags: html

Как в шаблон написанный в HTML 5 вставить документ написанный в PHP?

Вот пример кода:

```
 !DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Студия веб-дизайна "У Виктора" &mdash; Free Fully Responsive HTML5 Bootstrap Template by FREEHTML5.co</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Free HTML5 Template by FREEHTML5.CO" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="free html5, free template, free bootstrap, html5, css3, mobile first, responsive" />
    <meta name="author" content="FREEHTML5.CO" />


  <!-- 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    FREE HTML5 TEMPLATE 
    DESIGNED & DEVELOPED by FREEHTML5.CO

    Website:        http://freehtml5.co/
    Email:          info@freehtml5.co
    Twitter:        http://twitter.com/fh5co
    Facebook:       https://www.facebook.com/fh5co

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->



    <!-- Facebook and Twitter integration -->
    <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:image" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:url" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:description" content=""/>
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="" />

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700|Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Animate -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!-- Flexslider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">
    <!-- Icomoon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


    <!-- Modernizr JS -->
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FOR IE9 below -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="fh5co-header">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Mobile Toggle Menu Button -->
            <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>
            <div id="fh5co-logo">
                <a href="index.html">Фотогалерея<span>.</span></a>
            </div>
            <nav id="fh5co-main-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="home">Главная</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="about">Обо мне</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="contact">Мои контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fh5co-main">
        <div class="fh5co-overlay-mobile"></div>
        <div id="fh5co-home" class="js-fullheight" data-section="home">

            <div class="flexslider">

                <div class="fh5co-overlay"></div>
                <div class="fh5co-text">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row text-center">
                            <h1 class="animate-box">Студия веб-дизайна "У Виктора"</h1>
                            <div class="fh5co-go animate-box">
                                <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-next">
                                    Моё портфолио
                                    <span><i class="icon-arrow-down2"></i></span>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="slides">
                <li style="background-image: url(images/slide_2.jpg);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></li>
                <li style="background-image: url(images/slide_1.jpg);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></li>
                <li style="background-image: url(images/slide_3.jpg);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Нужно вставить вот такой код:

```
<?
/*
НАСТРОЙКИ САЙТА
-----------------------------------------*/

$adminemail = 'demoexpert@yandex.ru'; // На эту почту будут приходить заявки с сайта


/*
Название сайта и его описание
-----------------------------------------*/
$sitename = 'Адвокат «<b>Ольга Иванова</b>»'; // Отображается в логотипе
$description = 'Юридические услуги для физических и юридических лиц'; // Отображается под логотипом


// Телефон или Скайп в шапке?
$phoneskype = 0; // 0 - Телефон, 1 - Скайп
$phonenumber = '8 800 000 00-00'; // номер телефона или логин Скайпа
$worktime = 'с 10:00 до 20:00'; // время работы



/*
Оформление сайта
-----------------------------------------*/
$bodybgcolor = '#111111'; // цвет заднего фона

$primarycolor = '#0363b5'; // главный цвет
$linkcolor = '#f94005'; // цвет ссылок при наведении курсора мышки


/*
SEO
-----------------------------------------*/
$seo_keywords = "частный юрист, адвокат, услуги юриста";// ключевые слова для seo, не больше 20 слов через запятую с пробелом

?>
```

Comment: `как в шаблон написанный в HTML 5 вставить документ написанный в PHP ` - никак....... если скрипт лежит на сервере, то можно переименовать `html` в `php` или `phtml`....и далее пользоваться конструкциями php....... или заставить `.htaccess` интерпретировать эти файлы как php..... в ином случае (без сервера) - нельзя ничего сделать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  А если у него `nginx`?

Comment: @EugenEray это как-то отменяет `.htaccess`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Ну да :) Если `nginx`  то нужно шаманить в `nginx.conf`

Comment: @EugenEray ну так это никак не отменяет использование `.htaccess` и возможность настроек в нём ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  ..... но на счет первоначальных настроек - возможно. точно не скажу

Answer (score 1):

Эмм.. В чем проблема? Смени расширение файла с `.html` на `.php` и пропиши в нужном месте вот это:

```php
//Можно через require
require "path-to-your-file/file.php";
//Или require_once
require_once "path-to-your-file/file.php";
//Или include
include "path-to-your-file/file.php";
//Или include_once
include_once "path-to-your-file/file.php";
```

Для безопасности можно такое написать:

```php
if(file_exists("path-to-your-file/file.php")){
     $file = "path-to-your-file/file.php";
     require_once($file);
}
else {
//В ином случае пиши сюда контент файла
/*
НАСТРОЙКИ САЙТА
-----------------------------------------*/

$adminemail = 'demoexpert@yandex.ru';
// На эту почту будут приходить заявки с сайта


/*
Название сайта и его описание
-----------------------------------------*/
$sitename = 'Адвокат «<b>Ольга Иванова</b>»'; // Отображается в логотипе
$description = 'Юридические услуги для физических и юридических лиц'; 
// Отображается под логотипом


// Телефон или Скайп в шапке?
$phoneskype = 0; // 0 - Телефон, 1 - Скайп
$phonenumber = '8 800 000 00-00'; // номер телефона или логин Скайпа
$worktime = 'с 10:00 до 20:00'; // время работы



/*
Оформление сайта
-----------------------------------------*/
$bodybgcolor = '#111111'; // цвет заднего фона

$primarycolor = '#0363b5'; // главный цвет
$linkcolor = '#f94005'; // цвет ссылок при наведении курсора мышки


/*
SEO
-----------------------------------------*/
$seo_keywords = "частный юрист, адвокат, услуги юриста";
// ключевые слова для seo, не больше 20 слов через запятую с пробелом
}

//Но при таком методе все переменные будут локальные, так что:
$_GLOBALS['seo_keywords'] = $seo_keywords;
//И так назначь все переменные.
```